# Shortcut for xcode "go back to last place" in the same file?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, shortcut

In the same big .m file, just want return back to previous place, what is the shortcut ?

As we know " control+command -> / -< " is good for switching back between different files, but it doesn't work for the same file.

Comment: it will work for same file. if changed your cursor position.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to go back to the previous place is to do `Undo` then `Redo`

Comment: I agree with this, sometimes I'll even add a single space character if I know I'm going to scroll away, so that when I hit undo I'm taken right back to that place.